# NPM Website - published a new package but can't view its page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I published an NPM package today (`jhp-serve`). I can `npm install` it, `npx` it, and it appears in search results (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=jhp). But somehow, when I click the link in the search results to view its page, I get a 503 *JSON* response (not even an HTML page) containing:

```
{"error":"Service Unavailable"}
```

Here's a link for convenience: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jhp-serve

It's been this way for hours now, so I don't think it's just a matter of waiting for the repository to fully propagate things. I'm baffled. Is this something I did, or is it NPM's problem? Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "bin": {
    "jhp-serve": "./index.js"
  },
  "name": "jhp-serve",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "JHP: Hypertext Preprocessor",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/brundonsmith/jhp"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "jhp",
    "php",
    "web",
    "website",
    "html",
    "server"
  ],
  "author": "Brandon Smith",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be not the only one, with that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61243433/npmjs-gives-errorservice-unavailable-for-published-package
I guess that npm has currently some issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Update: it resolved on its own after nearly 24 hours. Guess it was on NPM's end.