# Npmjs gives {"error":"Service Unavailable"} for published package

Tags: javascript, npm

I made a new package and when I publish the package and browse https://www.npmjs.com/package/MY_PACKAGE

it gives the following error

[image]

What the hell is happening!, I've tried so many times all give the same error :(

By the way, I've checked the console and found that request responses with 503 status code.

Comment: You seem to be not the only one, with that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242971/npm-website-published-a-new-package-but-cant-view-its-page I guess that npm has currently some issues here.

Comment: Hi @mustapha have you been able to resolve it? Been having same issue since

Comment: It works now without any problems, check your package, I think now it's going to work also.